# Blank screen after installing and runnng Strapi CLI

Tags: strapi

I just installed Strapi CLI and after running **npm run deploy** I don't have any error in console or terminal, but admin page is blank:
[Admin page on localhost:1337/admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcXxB.png)

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem running Strapi 4.2.2 locally. My browser's console gave the error `Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript`.

Turns out my app had somehow gotten in a bad state. Once I ran `npm run-script strapi build`, and then re-launched Strapi, everything worked.